# Anyone know how to escape spaces in Azure Cli?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

I am running

```
$nameLine= az boards iteration team list --team "DevOpsTesting Team" --timeframe current --project DevOpsTesting | findstr "name" 
$nameOnly = (select-string ":(.*)" -inputobject $name).Matches.Groups[1].Value.Replace(",","")
az boards work-item create --title Test  --type Task --project DevOpsTesting --iteration DevOpsTesting\\$nameOnly --assigned-to A.B@gmail.com --fields "Description=PR is open, please test the new exe version and approve Priority=2"
```

But because the value of nameOnly is "Sprint 7" I am getting an error

```
az : ERROR: unrecognized arguments: 7
At line:4 char:1
```

..?
thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If spaces are used within a iteration, then enclose in double-quotes, in your case you could add the doule-quotes like:

```
--iteration "DevOpsTesting\\$nameOnly"
```